# Using scrollTo plugin after .load()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, scrollto

I have a div the has overflow:scroll; on it, this means that the div needs to be scrolled to the bottom on page load.

I have used the scrollTo plugin and it works fine, but when I replace the content in the div and move it to an external page and then use:

```
    $('document').ready(function()
    {
        $('#div').load("pagetoload.php").show();
    });
```

It doesn't scroll as it should?

This is my scrollTo code

```
    $('#div').scrollTo( { top:800, left:0}, 800 );
```

When I put that code after the load it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the callback function of .load:

```
$('#div').load("pagetoload.php", function(){
  $('#div').scrollTo( { top:800, left:0}, 800 );
}).show();
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

load runs asynchronously. That means it happens later. So your show() command, and the scroll run when there is nothing there. Then the load happens after that is all done.

You need to use the callback function of load, and put your code there.

```
$('#div').load("pagetoload.php", function(responseText, textStatus) { ... } )
```

Also: You do not need a `scrollTo` plugin for something as simple as what your are doing. Just use `scrollTop()` and `scrollLeft()` directly instead.